# How to preserve current view after api call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Before asp.net core I would invoke a web api from a button by writing some jquery from behind the button click.

I would then handle the data returned from that api call.

Currently I have a view.  this view contains a pop up window. In that window I have 3 div sections.

Login
Registration
ForgottenPassword

Focusing on Registration div I allow user to enter email/password/confirm password and let them press a button that calls my web api to validate this process.

So, this is my parent view snippet:

```
@model InformedWorker.Services.Models.Account

<div id="divLogForm" class="modal-dialog" style="display:none;position:absolute; ">
    <div style="background-color: #fefefe;margin: auto;padding: 20px;border: 1px solid #888;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button id="btnClose" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="hdrTitle">LogIn</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Segments/_Registration.cshtml", Model.Registration);}
            @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Segments/_LogIn.cshtml", Model.LogIn);}
            @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Segments/_ForgottenRegistration.cshtml", Model.ForgottenloginDetails);}
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My registration partial view is this:

```
@model InformedWorker.Services.Models.Registration
@*

*@
<div class="row" style="display:none" id="divRegistration">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" value="@Model.EmailAddress" required="" title="Please enter you username" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" value="" required="" title="Please enter your password">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" value="" required="" title="Please confirm your password">
            </div>
            <div id="registerErrorMsg" class="alert alert-error hide">Invalid registration</div>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="api/Registration" asp-action="Register" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="lead">Already Registered?</p>
        <p><a onclick="showLogInPage();" class="btn btn-info btn-block">LogIn</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My account Model is this:

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountRef { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Email address not found")]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of Entry")]
    public DateTime DOE { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public bool Activated { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Registration Registration { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public LogIn LogIn { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ForgottenRegistration ForgottenRegistration { get; set; }
}
```

My homeController is this:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //var home = new Services.Models.Home();
        //home.MyTest = _localizer["ActivationEmailSent"];
        //return View(home);
        var test = new Services.Models.Account();

        test.Registration = new Services.Models.Registration();
        test.Registration.EmailAddress = "aaa";

        return View(test);
        //return View(new Services.Models.Account());
    }
```

My Registration Web api is this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class Registration : Controller
{
    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(Registration Account)//int id)
    {
        return "Error in reg";
    }
}
```

so my question is that when api is called the whole page page is replaced with 'value'.

how would I parse the data and populate the form fields with the result and preserve the original view?

Should i revert back to jquery and make api call that way?

Have I got this fundamentally wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I would be making AJAX calls to get/post data from/to web APIs. jQuery or using a modern JavaScript framework like Angular etc.

Comment: @Ignas thanks.  I was getting confused by the fact I COULD call this api from the api-controller attributes. I did not know what the asp.net core was capable of in this context. At least this minimises my migration :) thanks